# How to script brightness turning down and up?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I am trying to create a applescript that puts my brightness to the max or minimum, but I don't know how to. I am trying to use this script

```
    repeat 10 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 122
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end repeat
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the necessary [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) are granted that permits UI scripting, this script programmatically adjusts the brightness of your screen by way of *System Preferences*:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of current pane
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
    process "System Preferences" to tell ¬
    window 1 to tell ¬
    tab groups to tell ¬
    groups to tell ¬
    sliders to set its value to 0.5 -- 0.0 to 1.0

quit application "System Preferences"
```

You can set that value you see to any decimal value between `0.0` (minimum brightness, display off) and `1.0` (maximum brightness).

Answer (score 1):

If I might suggest another alternative, I would offer the `brightness` command, installed from either https://github.com/nriley/brightness or `brew install brightness`.

Then you can easily switch to any brightness level between 0 (dark) and 1 (full power) with `brightness .5` being ½-full.

You could call `brightness` from an AppleScript if this to be an AppleScript solution.

Answer (score -1):

With your apple script attempt this is possible.

To dim your display to minimum brightness:

```
repeat 32 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 107
    end tell
end repeat
```

To brighten up your display to maximum brightness:

```
repeat 32 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 113
    end tell
end repeat
```